# Using properties of BindingNavigator

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've made a form where I can scroll through some rows in a SQL with the `BindingNavigator`-control.

Now I want to use the properties of this control in my code. Is it somehow possible to check if it has reach the last page/row? I want a button to be displayed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through listening for the `PositionChanged` event of the `BindingSource` that the `BindingNavigator` uses:

```
Private Sub myBinding_PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myBinding.PositionChanged
  If myBinding.Position = myBinding.Count - 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Last One!")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm!